# How many hash functions does my bloom filter need?

Tags: algorithm, bloom-filter

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) says:

> An empty Bloom filter is a bit array of m bits, all set to 0. There must also be k different hash functions defined, each of which maps or hashes some set element to one of the m array positions with a uniform random distribution.

I read the article, but what I don't understand is how k is determined. Is it a function of the table size?

Also, in hash tables I've written I used a simple but effective algorithm for automatically growing the hash's size. Basically, if ever more than 50% of the buckets in the table were filled, I would double the size of the table. I suspect you might still want to do this with a bloom filter to reduce false positives. Correct ?

Answer (score 59):

Given:

- **`n`**: how many items you expect to have in your filter (e.g. [216,553](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145633/6654))
- **`p`**: your acceptable false positive rate {0..1} (e.g. `0.01` → 1%)

we want to calculate:

- **`m`**: the number of bits needed in the bloom filter
- **`k`**: the number of hash functions we should apply

The formulas:

`m = -n*ln(p) / (ln(2)^2)` *the number of bits*
`k = m/n * ln(2)` *the number of hash functions*

In our case:

- `m` = `-216553*ln(0.01) / (ln(2)^2)` = `997263 / 0.48045` = `2,075,686` bits (253 kB)
- `k` = `m/n * ln(2)` = `2075686/216553 * 0.693147` = `6.46` hash functions (7 hash functions)

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: Note that due to rounding/truncating differences and/or precision of logarithm function, you might not get the exact same numbers for the example if you run those equations through your language of choice. For me, `m = 2075674` and `k = 6.64`. Either way, round up both values to nearest integer, and your false positive rate will be close enough. It would be interesting to have the equation to re-calculate the *actual* value of `p`, using your computed/rounded `m` and `k` values. Again though, there should be no need to worry about having precise values; ballpark is good enough.

Comment: Found the equation to calculate the actual value of `p` given one's computed `m` and `k` - interesting to compare to see how any rounding may have affected your acceptable false positive rate. `e` is the mathematical constant, not a dynamic value. `p = e^(-(m / n) * (ln(2)^2))` - thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24071581/2609094

Comment: note that `k = -log2(p) = log2(1/p)` which is helpful if you dont want to compute `m`. In my usecase - I am using a library that only accept `n` & `k` as input.

Answer (score 19):

If you read further down in the [Wikipedia article about Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), then you find a section *Probability of false positives*. This section explains how the number of hash functions influences the probabilities of false positives and gives you the formula to determine *k* from the desired expected prob. of false positives.

---

Quote from the Wikipedia article:

> Obviously, the probability of false
>   positives decreases as m (the number
>   of bits in the array) increases, and
>   increases as n (the number of inserted
>   elements) increases. For a given m and
>   n, the value of k (the number of hash
>   functions) that minimizes the
>   probability is
>
> [image: formula]

Answer (score 6):

And to have it laid out in a neat little table:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cao/papers/summary-cache/node8.html

Answer (score 3):

Given a number of bits per key you want to "invest", the best k is:

```
max(1, round(bitsPerKey * log(2)))
```

Where `max` is the higher of the two, `round` rounds to the nearest integer, `log` is the natural logarithm (base e).

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent [online bloomfilter](https://hur.st/bloomfilter) calculator.

This interactive bloom filter calculator lets you estimate and find out coefficients for your bloom filter needs. It also shows you graphs to see results visually and provides all the formulas
 For example, calculations for 216,553 `n` items with probability `p` of 0.01:

[image]

```
n = ceil(m / (-k / log(1 - exp(log(p) / k))))
p = pow(1 - exp(-k / (m / n)), k)
m = ceil((n * log(p)) / log(1 / pow(2, log(2))));
k = round((m / n) * log(2));
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but while the website computes a similar result to other answers here, the equation they give for m doesn't seem to work?