# How do hash values map to the vector in a bloom filter?

Tags: algorithm, vector, hash, bloom-filter

When implementing a bloom filter there are a few potential moving parts:

m = size of bit vector
n = items (expected to be) inserted into filter
k = number of hashes to be used

I understand that there are optimum relationships between m/n and k however I haven't found a clear explanation of how to map k hashes onto the bit vector for larger values of m.

In nearly every example I read people use values of m that are trivial (>256) and they show the hash functions heavily overlapping. For less than 256bits it's easy to imagine having k 256bit hash functions and ORing them to the vector.

As m gets larger to reduce the false positive rate for large values of n I'm not sure how the hashes should be mapped to the vector. I've seen hint of ideas such as partitioning the vector and applying "independent" (e.g. different murmur seeds) hashes to each 128bit section of the vector. However I haven't seen a concrete example of how to implement bloom filters for larger n/m values.

Comment: I think, I do not get your question here. The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) describes the math behind choosing apropriate values of m, n and k. I would never partition the vector of bits. I do not see how this can be helpful. I would always use all the bits for every hash function. I do not see a general difference between Arrays smaller, or larger 256 bit. Though, 256 bit is quite small, if you have such small vectors, a bloom filter might not be an appropriate data structure for your problem.

Comment: Yeah. I'm going to close the question. Somehow I missed the point that each hash maps to a single bit of the vector, rather than each hash ORs with the vector. I'm going to blame misleading diagrams in various explanations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many hash functions does my bloom filter need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658439/how-many-hash-functions-does-my-bloom-filter-need)

Answer (score 0):

When I studied Bloom filters, the page below has helped me a lot:

http://matthias.vallentin.net/blog/2011/06/a-garden-variety-of-bloom-filters/

All described there is implemented as an open-source library. Looking at its sources also was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When there are that amount of elements I would rather rely on simplified Cryptography hash functions :)